# Parsing json response from Google Geocode

Tags: php, arrays, json, google-maps, google-api

I'm trying to parse a response from a Google API.

Im wondering if there is an easy/efficient way of going about parsing this array in php to get the data from the 'address_components' array.

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "10",
           "short_name" : "10",
           "types" : [ "street_number" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Downing Street",
           "short_name" : "Downing St",
           "types" : [ "route" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Westminster",
           "short_name" : "Westminster",
           "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "London",
           "short_name" : "London",
           "types" : [ "postal_town" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Greater London",
           "short_name" : "Greater London",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "England",
           "short_name" : "England",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "United Kingdom",
           "short_name" : "GB",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "SW1A 2AA",
           "short_name" : "SW1A 2AA",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "10 Downing St, Westminster, London SW1A 2AA, UK",
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 51.5033635,
           "lng" : -0.1276248
        },
        "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 51.5047124802915,
              "lng" : -0.126275819708498
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 51.5020145197085,
              "lng" : -0.128973780291502
           }
        }
     },
     "place_id" : "ChIJRxzRQcUEdkgRGVaKyzmkgvg",
     "types" : [ "establishment", "point_of_interest" ]
  }
],
"status" : "OK"
}
```

My initial method was for run a loop through the array and creating a new array and setting the key to the "types", but I ran into some issues where there was more than one option for "types"

Comment: what is your desired output ?

Comment: @RamRaider my aim is to get an array with the **"address_components"** array where **"types"** would be the key and **"long_name"** would be the value.

Comment: javascript doesn't support arrays with names for keys -

Comment: @RamRaider Im using PHP, so the response is a json array and ill output it to an assoc array

Comment: and where the `types` has multiple values which would you use as the key?

Comment: @RamRaider From what I've seen the first option is the one I want every time, but the documentation doesn't say if that changes or not, so I was thinking some sort of search would be a better option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data='{
   "results" : [
      {
     "address_components" : [
        {
           "long_name" : "10",
           "short_name" : "10",
           "types" : [ "street_number" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Downing Street",
           "short_name" : "Downing St",
           "types" : [ "route" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Westminster",
           "short_name" : "Westminster",
           "types" : [ "neighborhood", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "London",
           "short_name" : "London",
           "types" : [ "postal_town" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "Greater London",
           "short_name" : "Greater London",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "England",
           "short_name" : "England",
           "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "United Kingdom",
           "short_name" : "GB",
           "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
        },
        {
           "long_name" : "SW1A 2AA",
           "short_name" : "SW1A 2AA",
           "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
        }
     ],
     "formatted_address" : "10 Downing St, Westminster, London SW1A 2AA, UK",
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 51.5033635,
           "lng" : -0.1276248
        },
        "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 51.5047124802915,
              "lng" : -0.126275819708498
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 51.5020145197085,
              "lng" : -0.128973780291502
           }
        }
     },
     "place_id" : "ChIJRxzRQcUEdkgRGVaKyzmkgvg",
     "types" : [ "establishment", "point_of_interest" ]
  }
],
"status" : "OK"
}';

$json=json_decode( $data );
if( $json->status=='OK' ){

    $data=array();/* store results */

    $results=$json->results;
    foreach( $results as $index => $obj ){
        $add=$obj->address_components;
        foreach( $add as $address ){
            $data[ $obj->formatted_address ][ implode( '-', array_values( $address->types ) ) ]=$address->long_name;
        }
    }
    echo '<pre>',print_r($data,1),'</pre>';
}
```

Will output:

```
Array
(
    [10 Downing St, Westminster, London SW1A 2AA, UK] => Array
        (
            [street_number] => 10
            [route] => Downing Street
            [neighborhood-political] => Westminster
            [postal_town] => London
            [administrative_area_level_2-political] => Greater London
            [administrative_area_level_1-political] => England
            [country-political] => United Kingdom
            [postal_code] => SW1A 2AA
        )

)
```

Comment: [The decode() true version](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e16f5168388e79a2f535af3d0d5a2e182ad24f72)  (no `array_values()`)

Comment: Horses for courses - the end result is the same though personally I prefer using object notation rather than array notation

Comment: Wasn't worth adding an answer.  Your way is perfectly fine.  I just wanted to show  the other way.  Good answer.